# how to use tooltip ui of jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery

i am trying to use the JQuery tool tip in asp.net application
but no where i would find how to call this tool tip if i move my mouse over a label or textbox in asp.net

any solution  on this  would  be  great t
Thank  you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to decorate your ASP.NET controls with CSS classes, say `has-tooltip`, then use a jQuery selector on the class to invoke the plugin.

```
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server"
           CssClass="has-tooltip"
           ToolTip="This provides some help..."
           Text="Label" />
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTB" runat="server"
             CssClass="has-tooltip"
             ToolTip="Enter your text here." />
```

Then in your scripts -- either injected or in mark up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('.has-tooltip').tooltip(); // invoke plugin on all elements with class
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

ASP.NET textboxes are just simple inputs that just have "fancy" ids.

Rick Strahl posted about it on his [blog](http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/42319.aspx) .

Comment: i  want  to if  i  take  my  cursor on the  label  i need  to display some  static  text . that  is what  i am  looking for

Comment: You're looking for a code given on a golden plate not for a solution. I gave you the answer, if you can't make anything out of it then that's your problem.